# Create compound object in javascript map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Trying to create a compound object in map but stuck at a point. map over an array which has start and end time and some event. below is code.

```
let detailsRes = Object.create({});

response.map((res, i) => {
    let start = new Date(moment(res.startTime).format('L'));
    let end = new Date(moment(res.endTime).format('L'));
    let current = new Date(start);
    while (current <= end) {
      date = [new Date(current).getFullYear(), new Date(current).getMonth() + 1, new Date(current).getDate()].join('-');
      detailsRes[date] == undefined ? (detailsRes[date] = 1) : (detailsRes[date] += 1);
      var newDate = current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
      current = new Date(newDate);
    }
  });
```

sample data

```
[{
    "endTime": "2020-12-06 16:30:00.000Z",
    "event": "Study",
    "startTime": "2020-12-06 12:30:00.000Z",
    'somedata':'js is good'
  },
  {
    "endTime": "2020-12-06 16:30:00.000Z",
    "event": "gym",
    "startTime": "2020-12-05 12:30:00.000Z",
    'somedata':'js is good'
  },
]
```

current output

```
  {5-12-2020 : 1, 6-12-2020 : 2 },
```

expected output

```
5-12-2020 : {
    totalcount: 1,  // 5 is only 1 time
    event1: 1 //gym
  },
  6-12-2020 : {
    totalcount:2,  // 2 times 6-12 is there so count is 2
    event1: 1, //gym
    event2: 1 // study
  }
```

so basically checking how many events are coming between dates, if event is between 1-12 to 3-12 then individual object of 1,2,3 and totalcount of 1 for each date and if any other events coming in between then increment that particular totalcounts. above given output of mine which is correct but trying to modify object like expected output. so i need this kind of object.

Comment: What if your event spans across multiple days (e.g. 5-th through 8-th of December) should the entries for *missing* days (i.e. `7-12-2020`) be created?

Comment: I dont follow what `event1:1` and `event2:1` refer to? is there just a new key `eventN` for every event always with the value `1`? Can there be `event1:2` if so how?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov yes, whatever the dates available, it will count it.

Comment: @Jamiec as i mentioned if date is coming multiple times, then it count that event, e.g date - 6-12 is in first event which is 5-12 to 6-12 and 6-12 is also event. so it will combine those 2 events and give count.

Comment: @DharmikSoni still not clear im afraid. See if my answer does what you want. If not clarify

Comment: You'll note I didnt ask about count - thats obvious. It was `eventN` I was asking about

Comment: @Jamiec event1 and event2 is just a property to name different events. as event1 : gym, event2: study. if gym comes 2 times withing date range then i will to ++ as with event2 and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225529/discussion-between-dharmiksoni-and-jamiec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are not exactly clear, but what is for sure is you should be using `reduce` not `map` for this.

Making the result an object is easy, see below, but I'm still not entirely clear how you build the `eventN` keys correctly. This certainly works for your test case presented here, if it doesn't work for what you want feel free to clarify and I will update as necessary.

```js
var response = [{
    "endTime": "2020-12-06 16:30:00.000Z",
    "event": "Study",
    "startTime": "2020-12-06 12:30:00.000Z",
    'somedata':'js is good'
  },
  {
    "endTime": "2020-12-06 16:30:00.000Z",
    "event": "gym",
    "startTime": "2020-12-05 12:30:00.000Z",
    'somedata':'js is good'
  },
]

let detailsRes = response.reduce((acc, res) => {
    let start = new Date(moment(res.startTime).format('L'));
    let end = new Date(moment(res.endTime).format('L'));
    let current = new Date(start);
    var n = 0;
    while (current <= end) {
      date = [new Date(current).getFullYear(), new Date(current).getMonth() + 1, new Date(current).getDate()].join('-');
      if(acc[date] == undefined) acc[date] = {totalcount:0}
      acc[date].totalcount++;
      acc[date]["event" + ++n] = 1;
      var newDate = current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
      current = new Date(newDate);
    }
    return acc
  }, {});
  
console.log(detailsRes)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this will work for me, thanks for quick help. Upvote.